# Can I modify my openshift git repo using ssh shell?

Tags: openshift

I have working app on OpenShift server. My question is - how to update openshift's git repo of my application, if I make some changes using ssh acsess to openshift? I mean not using all this stuff with pull/push to my local mashine.

Comment: I think you really should be [using git](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-modifying-applications.html) for code changes. The push will [build and deploy](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#openshift-builds) your change. Maybe if you describe in more details what would you like to achieve, someone may share their experience on alternate ways of updating apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to *modify source code without using git.* I am not sure why you would want that. All that stuff with pull/push gives you a version control flexibility which can save you a lot of time when you screw up one thing. For example, you push brand new UI to production, which turns out to be buggy. With git, you have flexibility to revert back to previous version, and work on different branch to fix the bug on UI.

OpenShift follows conventional app structure. Git for source control, maven for build, jbosseap(for example) for app server, jenkins for continuous integration, etc. So, when you push using git, OpenShift will automatically build using maven, then deploy to the server.

If you would like to disregard all that advantages that OpenShift has to offer, use `rhc ssh appname` to directly work on the server.

Comment: Sanks for you answer, yes I'm already modified my project structure and working process, so now I can easy update it with git.

Comment: Is there a way to upload a secret file using git? For example, local.properties that contains DB user/pass and name

Comment: `git add filepath`

It's best not to upload your secret file to git repository, keep it in server's env var. And the file name local.properties will definitely scare me if I see it on git repo - this can ruin other's workspace.